# Simple queue distribution scenario with pub/sub WMQ

Tags: ibm-mq, publish-subscribe

Using WebSphere MQ I want to setup up a topic that uses queues, so that when an application or inbound cluster connection attempts to put a message to a “queue”, it 
actually uses a topic, and publishes it to 2 subscriptions, which are 
themselves 2 separate queues.    In essence, I want to go from an inbound 
queue by name, but map it to 2 separate queues, like

AF_TO_DAAS  is the inbound topic/which today is an actual 
cluster queue alias

=>Goes to AF_TO_APP1 and
=>Goes to AF_TO_APP2

Sort of like if these were queues on a distribution list I suppose.

Those two things are local queues.

I’m getting lost in the /topic/node business mapping it to subscriptions 
and model queues and what not …

Comment: I added tags and full product name to assist with searches. Deleted the sig line as per SO guidelines.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

WebSphere MQ allows an alias to point to a queue or a topic.  It also provides a means to create a durable subscription administratively.  To accomplish this setup, you connect the dots by replacing the existing alias with one that points to a topic.  Then use two administrative subscriptions to route publications to the two (or more) queues.

```
* First, define the topic
DEFINE TOPIC('AF_TO_DAAS.TOPIC') +
   TOPICSTR('AF_TO_DAAS') +
   REPLACE

* Now, create an alias over the topic.
* Sending apps think this is a queue.
DEFINE QALIAS('AF_TO_DAAS') +
   TARGET('AF_TO_DAAS.TOPIC') +
   TARGTYPE(TOPIC) +
   REPLACE

* Queues for the two recvr apps
DEFINE QLOCAL('AF_TO_APP1') +
   REPLACE

DEFINE QLOCAL('AF_TO_APP2') +
   REPLACE

* Now set up adminsitrative subs to route
* messages to the two app queues.
DEFINE SUB('AF_TO_DAAS.SUB') +
   TOPICSTR('') +
   TOPICOBJ('AF_TO_DAAS.TOPIC') +
   DEST('AF_TO_APP1') +
   PSPROP(NONE) +
   REPLACE

DEFINE SUB('AF_TO_APP2.SUB') +
   TOPICSTR('') +
   TOPICOBJ('AF_TO_DAAS.TOPIC') +
   DEST('AF_TO_APP2') +
   PSPROP(NONE) +
   REPLACE
```

Because this is a publication, the messages will contain a property `Top` which contains the topic string. The `PSPROP(NONE)` in the subscription entries causes this to be suppressed so the messages look like the original publication.

Note also that the `MQMD.MsgID` on the publications is *different* than it is on the original message.

Comment: Perfect... thanks!  I'd vote but i'm numbered among the "unvotables" it seems and as such, am bereft of the opportunity to do so... I guess I could ask a bunch of questions that have been bothering me lately and perhaps i'll graduate to voting member.

Comment: T.Rob, in the above example shouldn't the SUB define statements have either `TOPICSTR` or `TOPICOBJ` filled in but not both?  The way it is above I believe it would resolve to topic string `AF_TO_DAAS/AF_TO_DAAS` which would not match the topic string of the `TOPICOBJ` that the `QALIAS` points to which is just `AF_TO_DAAS`.